# Can MathJax just leave the page blank when it fails to parse math instead of showing it red?

Tags: mathjax

When MathJax fails to recognize a symbol (like `\lightning`) it displays the contents in red.

Is there a possibility to just leave the tag blank instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `errorSettings` block controls the error messages produced when there is an internal error in MathJax (the "Math Processing Error").  TeX parsing errors are controlled by the TeX `noErrors` and `noUndefined` extensions.  You can change the color from red to black, for example, using the [options for `noUndefined`](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#noundefined).  Place

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {noUndefined: {attribtues: {mathcolor: "black"}}}
});
</script>
```

in your HTML file *before* the script that loads `MathJax.js` itself.

Alternatively, if you really want unknown macros to be ignored completely, then you could use

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
  MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Parse.Augment({csUndefined: function () {}});
},20);
</script>
```

to replace the function that handles undefined control sequences by one that does nothing.

Comment: Thanks! I also found `TeX: { noUndefined: { disabled: true } }`

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to adjust the error message? I think about a message like "Rendering error" or something similar.

Comment: @moose, do you mean the "[Math Processing Error]" or the error due to the undefined macro?  If the first, "Rendering error" might not be appropriate, since the problem need not be in the rendering portion of the code (it could be input processing, for example).

Answer (score 0):

See [MathJax The Core Configuration Options](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/hub.html). The `errorSettings` options describe how to change the responds to error.

Comment: Could you please give an example? I tried `MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]},
  errorSettings: {message: ["[math]"]}
});` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

After couple of hours I have found the solution:

For the debuggind step, you must register signals listener like this:

```
MathJax.Hub.signal.Interest(
  function (message) {console.log(message)}
);
```

This listener listen on all signal, so you must find specyffic signal. In my case it was:

> MathML Jax - parse error

When you have your signal you can register listener for that one, for eg.:

```
   MathJax.Hub.Register.MessageHook("MathML Jax - parse error",function (message) {
   console.log('error listener');
   });
```